# decision tree component

Tags: c#

could you help me find a component that draw such a tree in c#.thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Winforms`?

if you use `Silverlight`/`WPF` , `Hierachical` templates is a good one. then you can style it as you want.

Answer (score 2):

What about http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/ ?
It's a .NET port of Graphviz, a powerful open source library.

Answer (score 1):

You could try yFiles. It's not cheap, but it's the best graph drawing library I know and its really powerful. http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_dotnetplatform_about.html